# How to identify the person in typing the message or not in chat?

Tags: javascript, chat, livechat, facebook-chat

Kindly excuse me if I am asking a simple question. Please don't hesitate to edit my question  to do the correct approach.

I am doing the `java` `Chat` project.

I think You are all aware of that in `facebook` and `GTalk` , when your friend is typing the message, You can able to notify that the `User is typing` message will be in your displayed in your end.

When he sent the message or completed the message typing , the `User is typing` message will be hidden.

How they are identifying that the other user is currently typing or not ?

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Is this built on Java or JavaScript? What are you using to handle network communication?

Comment: I am looking for `javascript`.How they are catching the events of other end users ?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are not the same thing. You should remove the [tag:java] tag. In addition, you should post or describe the code you have written so far.

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea to implement this.I need only the Idea to implement this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question doesnt include any code. This answer has to stay basic.

If your using JavaScript there many ways you could watch if the users typing:

For example if the user is focused on the input box and there is a key down event then send an ajax message saying "USER ID TYPING" then the server can handle that.

I think this is a similar question: ["User is typing" function in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963810/user-is-typing-function-in-chat)

Please give some code so we are able to help!

-PLEASE ALSO NOTE-

Your implementation depends on what server side platform your using and how you want to interact.

I've done something similar in PHP where every 10 seconds i would see if there's a change if there i would send a AJAX request to PHP then update the clients that need to know that information

And for the message hiding or showing you can use:

JavaScript to change the visibility of the span that contains the message.

If you use jQuery then its `$('#spanID').hide()` or `$('#spanID').show()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... `"User is typing" function in chat` question  is exactly matches to me. But How can I identify that my friend is typing or not in my browser ?That is not an answer for my question. It displays that the same user is typing or not only in his browser? and not his friend browser

Comment: As i said send a message to the server and teh server can send one to the other client