# How to implement "user is typing" functionality and send to server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code that detects whether user is typing based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963810/user-is-typing-function-in-chat). I would like to send the response to the server via ajax, by placing my ajax code somewhere in the if/else statement, but am not sure how.

```
var textarea = $('#textarea');
var typingStatus = $('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970, actually some time in the past
var typingDelayMillis = 5000; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message

function refreshTypingStatus() {
  if (!textarea.is(':focus') ||
      textarea.val() == '' ||
      new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
    typingStatus.html('No one is typing -blank space.');
  } else {
    typingStatus.html('User is typing...');
  }
}
function updateLastTypedTime() {
  lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

What I have tried so far:

```
var textarea = $('#chatbox');
var typingStatus = $('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970, actually some time in the past
var typingDelayMillis = 5000; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message

function refreshTypingStatus() {
  if (!textarea.is(':focus') ||
      textarea.val() == '' ||
      new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
    typingStatus.html('No one is typing -blank space.');
  } else {
    typingStatus.html('User is typing...');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "usertypes.php?v=<?php echo $usarr; ?>",
    });
  }
}

function updateLastTypedTime() {
  lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

However, mine doesn't seem to be sending any reasponse. So I'm not sure if the placement of the ajax code is correct. Can anyone explain where am I going wrong?

Comment: My code worked . i had a problem with the PHP code. I am sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ajax code on keypress event. 
In your case you should use your ajax code inside ***updateLastTypedTime*** function  instead writing it inside callback of **setInterval** which executes 10 times in 1 second.

```
<script>
    var textarea = $('#chatbox');
    var typingStatus = $('#typing_on');
    var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970, actually some time in the past
    var typingDelayMillis = 5000; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message

    function refreshTypingStatus() {

      if (!textarea.is(':focus') ||
          textarea.val() == '' ||
          new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
        typingStatus.html('No one is typing -blank space.');
      } else {
        typingStatus.html('User is typing...');



      }
    }

    function updateLastTypedTime() {
      lastTypedTime = new Date();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {var: 'value'},
          url: "usertypes.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // if error , code here.. 
          }
        });
    }

    setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
    textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
    textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);

</script>
```

Comment: do you have any example i try out

Answer (score 2):

Please check this again :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    var typing = false;
    var timeout = undefined;
    var typingDelayMillis = 1000;

    function timeoutFunction() {
        typing = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "usertypes.php?v=<?php echo $usarr; ?>&isTyping="+typing,
        });
        $('#typing_on').html("");
    }
    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    $('#chatbox').keypress(function(e) {
        if (typing === false && $("#chatbox").is(":focus")) {
            delay(function() {
                timeoutFunction();
            }, typingDelayMillis);
            typing = true;
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "usertypes.php?v=<?php echo $usarr; ?>&isTyping="+typing,
            });
            $('#typing_on').html("user types...");
        }
    });

    $('#chatbox').on("blur", function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, typingDelayMillis);
    })
});
```

online demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/vo46gehw/5/

Comment: I have tested your code but its like it is not detecting whether user is typing https://jsfiddle.net/krushio/vo46gehw/